# Add DLL in window Application

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport

I Add Dll Using Add Reference But When I run the Project DLL Missing Error Occurred.

I see this Dll in bin folder But Missing error Occured

Answer (score 2):

Please remove the reference, add it again, clean the solution and rebuild it. That should resolve the issue.